# Get data-filter attribute of all divs

Tags: php, html

I have following html:

```
<div class="" data-filter="01">
    ...
</div>
<div class="" data-filter="02356">
    ....
</div>
<div class="" data-filter="02356">
    ...
</div>
```

How can I get the data-filter attribute of all those divs in PHP?

I've tried something like

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("items.html");

foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item){
    echo $item->getAttribute('data-filter');
}
```

but that throws `Call to undefined method error`.

Comment: Call to what `undefined method`?

Comment: @u_mulder Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMDocumentType::getAttribute()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[@class='']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo "Found: " . $entry->getAttribute("attrloc");
}
```

or use this php

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: But I have nested divs inside.. This will get them too right? But that's not something I want

Comment: $query = "//div[@data-filter]"; change the query this will get only div that has attribute data-filter

Comment: Thanks! But I have some difficulties with that. I need to filter out every div that doesn't contains str as substring in data-filter attribute. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below: need to cahnge method in foreach

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("items.html");

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') as $item){    
  echo $item->getAttribute('data-filter');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTMLFile("items.html");

   $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

   if (!is_null($elements)) {
   foreach ($elements as $element) {
       echo $element->getAttribute('data-filter').'<br>';
   }
```

For more information regarding this, please see [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).